# adfs and gwt webapp intergration

Tags: gwt, callback, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

I want to do login using the adfs. The scenario goes like this:
1. user access my web-app link where there will be a login button on click of it the call is to be made into the adfs.
2. if adfs session is already established then its should redirect me back to my application with the graph like thing as in facebook from wherein i can validate the user and use its my app.
3. if adfs session not present it will  provide the adfs login screen and then after login it will redirect back to application with some graph like object.

I want to achieve the above scenario how should i go about it without making use of openam or opensso or Shibboleth.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web-app is ASP.NET? If so, you need to add WIF.

When the user accesses a protected page, WIF intercepts the call and redirects you to the ADFS login screen.

You typically don't have the Login button inside your application (although there are ways to fudge it).

Regarding the "graph like thing" - not sure what you are referring to but ADFS can return any attribute like name, email etc. that reside in AD or in a SQL DB.

**Update**

You can go two ways:

- Install something like OpenAM or PingFederate which will handle your Java application and federates with ADFS
- Use the [About the Oracle OpenSSO Fedlet](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17842_01/doc.1111/e17847/about.htm) or the OpenAM one,

Comment: my webapp is in java and i didnt found any WIF pulgin for java. And the "graph like thing" is nothing but you can say the response sent back from adfs...   Is there any other way to go about it?

Comment: hey can you help me with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454088/facing-issue-in-the-adfs-and-fedlet-fedration