# HTTP Status 500 - Null input expection while redirecting to fedlet from adfs

Tags: response.redirect, adfs2.0, federation

When i access my fedlet it redirects me to adfs login screen wherein I enter my credential and
then from that login page I am redirect to the fedlet application page where it shows "HTTP Status 500 - Null input " exception. I am not getting what must be going wrong. Please can anyone help me with the solution.

am also enclosing the decoded response sent back to help :
"

    http://aaa.domain.com/adfs/services/trust
    
        
    
    
        
            
            
                
                    
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                CN=sso_te, OU=IT, O=comapnyname
                                1352204053
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        fHQDdZB2QYtpvmkjA+k+z2xDcIM8iE7esA9qpeiSvDsiPnfw5QoVKFis16wkA0XHIeZA4rLn0OWZ2gkAkx3GAVCCQe1MDpET/VGg1YcLs60YD3gu7zH2KZHERXwamxR4yHpT7Sf4Gh/Wwl98kJ644SZAwy2sC7xsqJKtQ+EpPFUZVs9Ii3pRfRscXIVysHqmMPuEdtCNQg0CkYNLNYiiU59Ki2i/CP0TJDI08uZ0r0ukqFNbatRpZ4ABTTum0/XLVzInvVwuRJfdrM/+cY4h7X5AG5mVDWbjZiqdACvv65vBHPW+CJsW5hP9y5O54/ICKvLOhCzXAFcMV+nGwmvLiA==
                    
                
            
            
                pCTZd0kNSw6DrM/R/eAKNGnL2sctIjeSgxC9dE75nRsgHudTZOhWslACex4vWYnJS4HN2Vw6YGJdw/vgid4CimY/VCC1YNKokru7eVXX4pRfQ3T95S8wP7UeBapblMqVPzvdNBpnQPy9MII/ZYFcauY6m+2AETJ0V0VmZI75dmsONT+1CsVVpwQm5x3+lRfchzV8mOO/Ynj3hQYQ4ubX+vYuy6hdQrJx3GG5pIv
            
        
    

"

Thanks a lot if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in Firefox - clear all cookies.

Start up the SAML tracer.

If you run in FireFox with the SAML tracer enabled, when you redirect to AFDS you should see a message in the SAML tracer marked with an orange SAML button. If you click on the SAML tab, the message with be a:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest ...
```

The response will be a:

```
<samlp:Response
```

and it will contain something like:

```
<AttributeStatement>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
                <AttributeValue>Joe Bloggs</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
                <AttributeValue>a@company.com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
```

which matches the claims you configured for the RP in ADFS.

Do you see anything like this?

I have no idea what your message represents.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply.. My response doesnt contain any attribute statement. I have posted the response got from the adfs. Please if u can click on edit and see the response and suggest whst should be done.

Comment: If i remove all the claims rule from the list and if I want to return only email-address to be returned successfully to the fedlet application then how should I go about it? and what steps should I take

Comment: Please bare me I really want this application to run. What Should I do to prevent this response from getting encrypted.

Comment: Get my email address from my profile and send me the fedlet config. file, the two idp xml files (normal and extended) and the two sp.xml files.

Comment: hey I am not able to located your mail address. Mine is mahesh@enasrm.com please mail ur is here so we can carry our further conversation. Thanks

Comment: Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     mahesh@enasrm.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
DNS Error: Domain name not found